# Word wrap of long words not working on windows phone

Tags: css

I am using the below css class to wrap the long words with width in % not fixed and this not working on Firefox and windows phones.

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;    
word-break: break-all;    
word-break: break-word;    
-webkit-hyphens: auto;    
-moz-hyphens: auto;    
-ms-hyphens: auto;    
hyphens: auto;    
width:100%;
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
word-break: break-word;
```

This statement in your code uses the wrong value for the associated property. The break-word value is used on the word-wrap property. Also it is fine that you are using percentages to establish where text should break, but if you have:

```
width: 100%;
```

This is telling the browser that you don't want it to break the text until the 100% mark which could be responsible for why you aren't seeing the text break at all. I can't see the rest of your code, but with these properties, I believe you are suppose to define a lang attribute on the parent element in. HTML of whichever text you are trying to break.This tells the browser where it is allowed to break the text. Some languages don't allow breaking in the text like Chinese so this is important. If this isn't the answer you are looking for maybe you can include additional code so I can get a better grasp of what issue you are facing.